# GNU Parallel fundamentals: how can I feed some parameter that is not in the last position?

Tags: gnu-parallel

How can I **parallelize** ping operations like these below using **GNU Parallel**?

```
ping -c 5 -S ${AdapterIP[1]} 8.8.8.8
ping -c 5 -S ${AdapterIP[2]} 8.8.8.8
ping -c 5 -S ${AdapterIP[3]} 8.8.8.8
```

**Problem**: I am using **FreeBSD**, so this change is not allowed (note the host parameter to ping must be the **last** one) on the syntax:

```
ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 -S ${AdapterIP[1]}
```

On **Linux** systems I just do:

```
parallel ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 -S ::: "${AdapterIP[@]}"
```

I have tested this method on FreeBSD:

```
    luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel ping -c 5 -S ::: "${AdapterIP[@]}" 8.8.8.8
usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize] [-g sweepminsize]
            [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait] [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl]
            [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout]
            [-W waittime] [-z tos] host
       ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait] [-l preload]
            [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
            [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
            [-z tos] mcast-group
usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize] [-g sweepminsize]
            [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait] [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl]
            [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout]
            [-W waittime] [-z tos] host
       ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait] [-l preload]
            [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
            [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
            [-z tos] mcast-group
usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize] [-g sweepminsize]
            [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait] [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl]
            [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout]
            [-W waittime] [-z tos] host
       ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait] [-l preload]
            [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
            [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
            [-z tos] mcast-group
```

... with no luck, as can be seen.

This is probably a dumb question, but I am new to GNU Parallel. Some help, please?

For those interested, this is a possible value of the **array** that will feed GNU Parallel:

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ echo ${AdapterIP[@]}
192.168.1.254 192.168.2.254 192.168.3.254
```

Comment: Spend an hour walking through the tutorial. Your command line will love you for it. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I have found to specify the parameter when not in the last position (the `--dry-run` flag is to not execute, just test):

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel --dry-run sudo ping -c 5 -S {1} 8.8.8.8 ::: "${AdapterIP[@]}"
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.2.254 8.8.8.8
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.3.254 8.8.8.8
```

Note the `{1}`.
It can be used with multiple parameters. Example for `{2}`:

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ parallel --dry-run sudo ping -c 5 -S {1} {2} ::: "${AdapterIP[@]}" ::: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.1.254 8.8.4.4
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.2.254 8.8.8.8
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.2.254 8.8.4.4
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.3.254 8.8.8.8
sudo ping -c 5 -S 192.168.3.254 8.8.4.4
```